# Laravel - Converting RAW query into Eloquent query (Update Query)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a table called partner_transaction. On this table i have 4 columns: **id, partner_id, type, amount**

```
|id|partner_id |type     |amount|
|--|------------|---------|------|
|1 |65          |Credit   |50    |
|2 |65          |Credit   |20    |
|3 |65          |Debit    |30    |
|4 |10          |Credit   |30    |
```

now i am introduce a new balance column(current balance) on this table like below.

```
|id|partner_id  |type     |amount|balance|
|--|------------|---------|------|-------|
|1 |65          |Credit   |50    |50     |
|2 |65          |Credit   |20    |70     |
|3 |65          |Debit    |30    |40     |
|4 |10          |Debit    |30    |-30    |
```

We wants to re-adjust all balance column by type for a specific partner(65). So we write a raw query -

```
update partner_transactions pt
inner join (
select
    id, (select sum(case type when 'Credit' then amount when 'Debit' then -amount end)
    from partner_transactions pt2
    where pt2.partner_id = pt1.partner_id and pt2.id <= pt1.id
    ) balance
    from partner_transactions pt1
    WHERE pt1.partner_id = 65
) ptx
on ptx.id = pt.id AND pt.partner_id = 65
set pt.balance = ptx.balance
WHERE pt.partner_id = 65
```

***We are using Laravel 5.2***. 
Now we wants to convert in eloquent. So we write 2 function.

**01. For calculating balance -**

```
private function calculateBalanceQuery()
    {
        return DB::table('partner_transactions as pt1')
            ->where('pt1.partner_id', 65)
            ->selectRaw("id, (select sum(case type when 'Credit' then amount when 'Debit' then -amount end)
                from partner_transactions pt2
                where pt2.partner_id = pt1.partner_id and pt2.id <= pt1.id) balance"
            );
    }
```

**02. For update partner_transaction_table -**

```
public function updateQuery()
    {
        return PartnerTransaction::join(DB::raw('(' . $this->calculateBalanceQuery()->toSql() . ') ptx'), function ($join) {
                $join->on('ptx.id', '=', 'partner_transactions.id')->on('partner_transactions.partner_id', '=', DB::raw("'65'"));
            })
            ->where('partner_transactions.partner_id', 65)
            ->update(['partner_transactions.balance' => 'ptx.balance']);
    }
```

But when execute this script, their was an error occurred.

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: update `partner_transactions` inner join (select id, (select sum(case type when 'Credit' then amount when 'Debit' then -amount end)
from partner_transactions pt2
where pt2.partner_id = pt1.partner_id and pt2.id <= pt1.id) balance from `partner_transactions` as `pt1` where `pt1`.`partner_id` = ptx.balance) ptx on `ptx`.`id` = `partner_transactions`.`id` and `partner_transactions`.`partner_id` = '65' set `partner_transactions`.`balance` = 65 where `partner_transactions`.`partner_id` = ?)
```

So how could we convert it.

Comment: `'ptx.balance'` will be treated as a string unless you wrap it in `DB::raw('ptx.balance')` on the other hand '65' does not need to be wrapped in DB::raw. Also you don't need to do `toSql` for the other query, the query builder instance should work

Comment: If i remove DB::raw(65) by only 65, then a error occurred - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '65' in 'on clause'

Comment: And after using this  - 
```
return PartnerTransaction::join(DB::raw('(' . $this->calculateBalanceQuery()->toSql() . ') ptx'), function ($join) {
                $join->on('ptx.id', '=', 'partner_transactions.id')->on('partner_transactions.partner_id', '=', 65);
            })
            ->where('partner_transactions.partner_id', 65)
            ->update(['partner_transactions.balance' => DB::raw('ptx.balance')]);
```
PDOException in Connection.php line 480:
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

at PDOStatement->execute(array('65')) in Connection.php line 480

Comment: You're already doing `where('partner_transactions.partner_id', 65)` why do you also join on that?

Comment: Yes, i think their is no need of this - ->on('partner_transactions.partner_id', '=', DB::raw("'65'"));

But i'm not understand why this error occurred. PDOException in Connection.php line 480:
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: at Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(object(MySqlConnection), 'update `partner_transactions` inner join (select id, (select sum(case type when 'Credit' then amount when 'Debit' then -amount end) from partner_transactions pt2 where pt2.partner_id = pt1.partner_id and pt2.id <= pt1.id) balance from `partner_transactions` as `pt1` where `pt1`.`partner_id` = ?) ptx on `ptx`.`id` = `partner_transactions`.`id` set `partner_transactions`.`balance` = ptx.balance where

Comment: You have a query which requires parameters in `calculateBalanceQuery` and then you are doing `toSql` on that which places the placeholders in the other query but does not transfer the parameters because whenever you do `where('a','=','b')` Laravel converts this to `WHERE a=?` and then binds a parameter with value `b` in the final query. You need to merge parameters **or not do `toSql` because it is breaking your query**